# Calculate a set of performance metrics from signals in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, confusion-matrix, false-positive

I have a dataframe containing three of my signals as follows:

[image]

- `rr_manually_cleaned` is the ground truth signal
- `rr_noisy` is the raw noisy signal
- `rr_filtered` is the output from an anomaly detector that has cleaned
  rr_noisy from detected anomalies

To evaluate the performance of the anomaly detector - I want to find out FP, FN, etc.

- For FN (false negative) - this would be the case where there is a
  data point in `rr_filtered` but not in `rr_manually_cleaned` (i.e. a NaN
  value) as this means the anomaly detector has failed to detect an
  anomaly
- For FP (false positive) - this would be the case where a datapoint
  exists in `rr_manually_cleaned` but not in `rr_filtered` meaning the
  anomaly detector detected an anomaly that should not be one

Using this setup - what is the best way of going about calculating FP, FN, and other relevant performance metrics (F1, Precision, Recall, etc.)? Is it possible to build a confusion matrix straight from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use isna() test for that.

```
df.loc[(~df['rr_filtered'].isna()) & (df['rr_manually_cleaned'].isna()), 'TEST'] = 'FN'

df.loc[(~df['rr_manually_cleaned'].isna()) & (df['rr_filtered'].isna()), 'TEST'] = 'FP'
```